# send axios request multipart/files

Tags: axios

I am trying to upload a photo to a webservice and the documentation clearly specifies that the request type is Multipart/files so I am trying this request with axios which always fails.

```
         HTTP.put(`/employees/${response.data.data.id}/photo`, { photo: this.image }, {headers: { put: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/files' }}})
           .then((profilePictureResponse) => {
             console.log(profilePictureResponse);
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             console.log(error.response);
           });
```

HTTP is an axios instance with default configurations but the default content-type is set to application/json